# How can I stop my hamster biting the bars on her cage?

Tags: hamsters, animal-handling, cage

My hamster is about 5 months old and she won’t stop biting the bars at the opening of her cage. She’s now got a little red mark on one side of her face because of it. Her cage is huge and she has plenty of toys, things to chew and treats too. I don’t want her to hurt herself!

Comment: From my experience, this means that they want a larger cage. If it's a syrian hamster, make sure that it has at least 450 sq. inches of floor space. (more is better).

Comment: Also, do you know which breed your hamster is? Syrians have slightly different needs than campbells.

Comment: Welcome to Pets.SE! Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help], especially [What does it mean if a question is closed](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). How big is her "huge" cage actually? These tiny animals have an insane instinct to run around, which means that a cage that seems huge for their body size can still be too small for their instincts.

Comment: Additional to the linked answered question: If it biting only the "door", maybe it is smart enough to know "sometimes it is open!" I notice this behavior in my rabbits sometimes.